# Cant find what the error is when compiling to iOS with flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

Ive tried most things i could find but can't fix the error. There seems to be something wrong with all my packages. The code compiles and works on android. When i try to compile the code in Xcode it stops when it reaches firebase_auth. The flutter version is 1.22.6, I've set the development target to 10 on the device.
The problems im getting is with everything, i can scroll up until it reaches max count.

```
   ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart:2052:7: Error: Can't assign to the final variable 'childrenInHitTestOrder'.
      childrenInHitTestOrder = _kEmptyChildList;
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart:2056:7: Error: Can't assign to the final variable 'childrenInTraversalOrder'.
      childrenInTraversalOrder = Int32List(childCount);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart:2062:7: Error: Can't assign to the final variable 'childrenInHitTestOrder'.
      childrenInHitTestOrder = Int32List(childCount);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart:3653:47: Error: Getter not found: 'isSlider'.
  bool get isSlider => _hasFlag(SemanticsFlag.isSlider);
                                              ^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart:3655:28: Error: Getter not found: 'isSlider'.
    _setFlag(SemanticsFlag.isSlider, value);
                           ^^^^^^^^
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on Benjamin’s
```

Added some more of the errors, its something with my localizations. But i added everything like its said in the howto for adding localizations for iOS. When i try to add that non nullable part it breaks my already written code since i didn't write for that.

```
../../flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/generated_cupertino_localizations.dart:1382:9: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental and requires language version of 2.10 or higher.
You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
  String? get timerPickerHourLabelMany => null;
        ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/generated_cupertino_localizations.dart:1385:9: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental and requires language version of 2.10 or higher.
You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
  String? get timerPickerHourLabelOne => 'sat';
        ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/generated_cupertino_localizations.dart:1391:9: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental and requires language version of 2.10 or higher.
You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
  String? get timerPickerHourLabelTwo => null;
        ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/generated_cupertino_localizations.dart:1394:9: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental and requires language version of 2.10 or higher.
You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
  String? get timerPickerHourLabelZero => null;
        ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/generated_cupertino_localizations.dart:1397:9: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental and requires language version of 2.10 or higher.
You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
  String? get timerPickerMinuteLabelFew => 'min.';
        ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/generated_cupertino_localizations.dart:1400:9: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental and requires language version of 2.10 or higher.
You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
  String? get timerPickerMinuteLabelMany => null;
        ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/generated_cupertino_localizations.dart:1403:9: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental and requires language version of 2.10 or higher.
You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
  String? get timerPickerMinuteLabelOne => 'min.';
        ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/generated_cupertino_localizations.dart:1409:9: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental and requires language version of 2.10 or higher.
You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
  String? get timerPickerMinuteLabelTwo => null;
        ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/generated_cupertino_localizations.dart:1412:9: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental and requires language version of 2.10 or higher.
You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
  String? get timerPickerMinuteLabelZero => null;
        ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/generated_cupertino_localizations.dart:1415:9: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental and requires language version of 2.10 or higher.
You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
  String? get timerPickerSecondLabelFew => 'sec.';
        ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/generated_cupertino_localizations.dart:1418:9: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental and requires language version of 2.10 or higher.
You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
  String? get timerPickerSecondLabelMany => null;
        ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/generated_cupertino_localizations.dart:1421:9: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental and requires language version of 2.10 or higher.
You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now, what i did was that i removed flutter, redownloaded the same version. compiled and now it installed on the device.